# How to reload project in VS with Target command before build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix, csproj, project-template, build-events

I am looking for a way to Reload a project OR all projects inside the Solution, with Target node , which is in **pre-build events node of .csproj file**

```
<Project>  
...  
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">  
    <!-- Insert tasks to run before build here -->  
</Target>  
<Target Name="AfterBuild">  
    <!-- Insert tasks to run after build here -->  
</Target>
```

I already read MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) but i could not find a way to reload project. I just know if sth can change .csproj file, IDE automatically reload the project.

Any advise for me please?

Does anyone have idea about **PreBuildEvent** at this part?

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
       <ErrorText> package(s) that are missing on this computer. </ErrorText>
     </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\.0.0.2\ />
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
     <PreBuildEvent>"$(ProjectDir)XXXXXXXXX WHAT TO DO TO RELOAD ???
```